# Default value to give MySQL UPDATE in order to NOT overwrite column value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm wondering if there's any special keyword I can use in a MySQL query in place of a value in the format `SET col = 'value'` in order to NOT over-ride the current entry for a particular column within a row.

For example, I have the following PHP method:

```
    public function update_item($id, $position = false, $title = false, $image_url = false, $paragraph = false) {
        $values     = "item_position = '$position', item_title ='$title', item_image_url = '$image_url', item_paragraph = '$paragraph'";
        $conditions = "item_id = '$id'";

        $query = Database::instance()->update_row($this->table, $values, $conditions);
    }
```

Within the above method, the variable `$values` stores all the values to be updated. At the moment I've defaulted each to `false` but I assume this will over-ride the existent values.

I would greatly appreciate any help as this would save me from writing a fair bit of possibly pointless PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

just do not list the column in your update, then it will not override the existing value

Comment: But the variable `$values` has them listed by default. I'm trying to see if there is a MySQL keyword or query element in order to prevent it from updating, as oppose to forming several lines of PHP without the need to.